# NoReverseMatch at /index/

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have been through all of the similar issues and I have gotten nowhere and I have gone through the djangogirls and the officail Django tutorials and as far as I can tell it should be working.

In the **polls/templates/index.html** file I have this:

```
[...]
{% if forms %}
    <ul>
        {% for form in forms %}
            <li>
                <h1><a href="{% url 'form_detail' pk=form.pk %}">
                    {{ form.fname }}
                </a></h1>
                [...]
```

In my **polls/urls.py** file I have this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    [...]
    url(r'^index/$', 'polls.views.site_index'),
    [...]
    url(r'^form/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.form_detail, name='form_detail'),
    [...]
```

In my **polls/views.py** file I have this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Nform, Choice, Question, Post
from django.template import loader
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib import auth
from django.db import models
from .form import PostForm

def site_index(request):
    forms = Nform.objects.order_by('-published_date')
    return render_to_response('polls/index.html', {'forms': forms})


def form_detail(request, pk):
    current_form = get_object_or_404(Nform, pk=pk)
    fame = current_form.fname
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.filter(for_form=fame).order_by('-pub_date')
    choice_quest_list = []
    text_quest_list = []
    form = PostForm()
    for i in range(len(latest_question_list)):
        if len(latest_question_list[i].choice_set.all()) == 0:
            text_quest_list.append(latest_question_list[i])
        else:
            choice_quest_list.append(latest_question_list[i])
    return render(request, 'polls/read_only.html', {'choice_quest_list': choice_quest_list, 'text_quest_list': text_quest_list, 'form_name': fame, 'form': form})
[...]
```

I am assume that I have made a very simple mistake somewhere and I would be very grateful to anyone who finds it.

See this [issue](https://github.com/Huaraz2/djangosite/issues/1) for pics.

[Here](https://github.com/Huaraz2/djangosite) is a link to my code.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have defined a variable named `app_name` in your application urls.py.

When you define that variable, it becomes your url namespace.

You either have to reverse your url like this:

```
<h1><a href="{% url 'polls:form_detail' pk=form.pk %}">
```

or remove the app_name variable to use the url name directly.

Read more about [reversing url names @ django-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls)